# Nginx doesn't redirect mutilple locations

Tags: nginx, location, reverse-proxy

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04) and everything works fine, until I try to use multiple location, such as:

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

It does not redirect and returns a 404 when I try to call them.

It works if I do it like this, but this way I can only use one app, which is not what I want...

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps `/app1/` ?

Comment: Can't believe it was something so simple! It worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: Lol, awesome! Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments: `/app1/` ;)